# How can I concatenate words on new lines from a txt file using batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file called test.txt that has something like the following,

> Hello
>   Goodbye

and I have a `batch` file that echos them out:

```
  @echo off
  SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
  FOR /F %%x in (test.txt) DO echo %%x
```

so this prints out:

```
Hello 
Goodbye
```

which is what I expect it to do, but how can I take this idea and make a variable that equals "Hello Goodbye" together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect each line in a variable and output it after the loop. For this you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), because the variable is read and modified within the same parenthesised block of code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Reset variable:
set "string="
for /F "delims=" %%X in (test.txt) do (
    rem Concatenate strings, separated by a SPACE:
    set "string=!string!%%X "
)
rem Return collected string, removing last SPACE:
echo(%string:~,-1%
```